# Datepicker custom button error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script where there is an extra button called "csa" in the datepicker panel. Now everything worked fine. When there was for example an input field with 2014-01-23 and when then clicked on the CSA button, the date changed + 6 months. Now we are in the 6th month. I get an error when i click the csa button. the date 2014-06-04 becomes 2014-00-4. But it should be 2014-06-04 + 6 months. But i see no error in my script....can someone help me out here?

```
$(function () {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "2014:2034",
          showButtonPanel: true,
          beforeShow: function (input) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  var buttonPane = $(input)
                      .datepicker("widget")
                      .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

                  var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">CSA</button>');
                  btn.unbind("click")
                      .bind("click", function () {
                          //$.datepicker._clearDate(input);
                          //alert('custom text');
                          var date = new Date(),
                              monthsToAdd = 7,
                              resultMonth =((date.getMonth()+monthsToAdd)%12),
                              displayMonth = (resultMonth < 10 ? '0'+ resultMonth: resultMonth);
                              $(input).datepicker("hide");
                              $(input).val(date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                              displayMonth + '-' + date.getDate());

                      });


                  btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

              }, 1);
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: A fiddle would be better to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
resultMonth =((date.getMonth()+monthsToAdd)%12),
```

with

```
resultMonth =(((date.getMonth()+1)+monthsToAdd)%12),
```

Reason :

`date.getMonth()` will return 5 for sixth month. As monthrange is 0-11

**[Demo Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bW8r5/3/)**

Comment: thx for your answer, but when i test the fiddle i get 2014-01-4 as i click on the csa button, and that is not 2014-06-04 + 6 months... i don't understand

Comment: It is because your code is taking current date(today's date) here `$(input).val(date.getFullYear() + '-' + displayMonth + '-' + date.getDate());`

Comment: how can i take the date that is in the input field and not todays date?

Comment: thx; the code works perfectly, but the problem is still the same...take the date off today. it is 2014-06-04 it should become 2014-12-04 but when i click on csa i get 2014-01-04 which isnt 6 but 7 months and the year didnt change to 2015. When i put the date 2014-07-01 in the input field i should get 2015-01-04 when i click on csa but i get 2014-01-04... somewhere there is an error

Comment: the dates and months work perfectly now, but the year doesnt change when it is after the 6 th mont  try 2014-07-14 for example, it becomes 2014-01-14, but the year must change to if it is + 6months it should be 2015-01-14 .